# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.displayName')

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with my code which I can not solve, the problem that appears is:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.displayName')
```

my code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import {StackNavigator} from "react-navigation";
import StartScreen from "../screens/Start";
import LoginScreen from "../screens/Login";

export default StackNavigator (
    {
        Start: {
            screen: StartScreen
        },
        Login: {
            screen: LoginScreen
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Start',
        navigationOptions: {
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#1C1C1C'
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
                textAlign: 'center',
                alignSelf: 'center',
                fontSize: 20,
                color: '#BBEDF8',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        }
    }
)
```

I know the error is in:

```
import LoginScreen from "../screens/Login";

Login: {
            screen: LoginScreen
        }
```

because when you delete them the error stops appearing, but I do not know if the problem is with the login screen that you send, or with something else, could you please help me?

Comment: Where do you use `. displayName` in your code? You should perhaps show the file where that is.

Comment: This is another question I have, because nowhere in the code is n.displayName written

Comment: There must be some component using that property, if you don't get the error when you remove the LoginScreen, the chances are it is there.

Comment: You were quite right, although that property is not explicit in the code, it was called in a component, and to solve it you had to install certain characters with "npm install @ types / tcomb-form-native", I thank you very much.